# Repaint on two panels do not work on second panel

Tags: java, swing, panel, repaint, panels

I have a problem by programming an user interface. I am using Swing.
I begin to create a Tabpane with 5 Tabs.
Tab 1 contains: Button1 and a textarea
Tab 2 contains: Button2 and a textarea
Tab 3 contains: Button3 and a textarea
Tab 4 contains: Button4 and Panel1
Tab 5 contains: Button5 and Panel2

This class MyClass implements the interface ActionListener and the method actionPerformed was overwritten like this (short version):

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener {

    //  Creating UI ... and so on

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button1) {
            //do something
        }
        // Exactly the same for button2 and button3

        if (e.getSource() == button4) {
            panel1.repaint(); // PANEL 1
        }
        if (e.getSource() == button5) {
            panel2.repaint(); // PANEL 2
        }
    }
}
```

I have two classes Panel1 and Panel2, which extend the class JPanel.

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    protected Panel1() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //DRAW SOMETHING ON PANEL1
    }
}
```

The class for Panel2 looks exactly like this class, but draws something on panel2.

My problem is now:

In MyClass i have created the UI and all components for it. This includes 5 buttons. On each of these 5 buttons i have called the method:
    buttonX.addActionListener( new MyClass() );

to do exactly what is defined in the actionPerformed() - method.

If i add this ActionListener to button1-3 : Everything works fine.
If i add this ActionListener to button1-4 (NOT 5) : button1-3 do what they should do and button4 repaints Panel1 correctly.
If i add this ActionListener to button1-3 and 5 (NOT 4) : button1-3 do what they should do and button5 repaints Panel2 correctly.
BUT if i add this ActionListener to button1-5 : button1-3 do what they should do and button5 repaints Panel2 correctly. BUT button4 does nothing!. So Panel1 was not repainted!

Can somebody explain me, why button1-3 always work; button4 and button5 work, if i add the ActionListener to just ONE of theses two buttons; BUT button4 does NOT work, if i add the ActionListener to all 5 buttons?!

Thanks guys for your help
Best regards
Alex

Comment: My guess is that you are messing up the instances buttonX in the actionListener since you are creating a new ActionListener each time, when you do `addActionListener.add(new MyClass())`, instead create 1 action listener and add the same to all. For example `addActionListener(this)`

Comment: You're leaving out key code that would help us diagnose your problem, so to solve this, you'll have to improve your question, or we'll have to engage in a little voodoo, but one perhaps related concern I have is that your description and code snippets suggests that you have program logic present inside of your paintComponent method, and if so, this should not be.

Comment: Bottom line -- try to avoid making us guess or do voodoo. Please make your question and your code more complete. Create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also -- avoid having your GUI class implement your listener as that's asking the class to do too much. Instead use either anonymous inner class or stand along listener classes.

Comment: hi guys, i have tried to create an minimal program to show this problem. But the problem was, that this example worked. I am completely confused... i will add some code to my question, if i can rebuild this problem. But thank you guys for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have GUI classes implement listener interfaces as it leads to classes with high coupling and low cohesion. Instead consider using anonymous inner classes for your simple one-off listener code. For instance:

```
button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    panel1.repaint();
  }
});
```

Having said this, I worry if your ActionListener is this simple, and suggests to me that you've got some class state-changing going on in panel1's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. Please understand that you do not have full control over when or even if paintComponent will be called, and also you don't ever want to hinder this method with non-painting code, and so you will want to keep all class state-changing code out of this method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's your problem exactly, but try to change

```
buttonX.addActionListener( new MyClass() );
```

to

```
buttonX.addActionListener(this);
```